# Wordpress: how to call method and output?

Tags: wordpress

I am using a Wordpress plugin found here https://github.com/hirezstudios/smite-api-wp . Issue I have is the readme says I need to:

```
      // call a method
      global $smiteAPI;
      $gods = $smiteAPI->getGods(1);
      // do whatever with the god data...
```

I understand I need to implement it on one of my .php files or generate a new one. However, I am unsure what call a method means or how to make the above work. The getGods(1) will return a .json file of all gods in a game called Smite; 1 tells the API english.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! That example you posted is literally calling a method ( `->`). A method is a function within a Class. The Class is set by the global variable `$smiteAPI` and the method (function) is the `getGods()`. The arrow (`->`) is "calling" the method from the class.

Comment: Sorry I did a poor job of explaining myself. Also thanks for the welcome! How would I use the above function in a .php file? I have been searching and really unsure how I would use it to generate the Gods list using the above method.

Comment: It really depends on how/where you want to use the data. What is your end goal with the data?